# fingerpint input using react , node , mysql

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fingerprint

Can anyone let me know how can we take user fingerprint and save those data in mysql server

I came to know about fingerprintjs library for react. Is that a right solution for me to use that api ?

Actually Im in need to take fingerprint and send those data to mysql server and update the record based on it. But currently I'm stuck at this fingerprint part.
I want to manually take the fingerprint and set ID for it in database and then start matching those fingerprints later.

Can anyone suggest how to proceed this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import FingerprintJS from '@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs';

const FingerprintCollector = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const collectFingerprint = async () => {
      const fp = await FingerprintJS.load();
      const result = await fp.get();

      // Assuming you have an API to send the fingerprint data to your server
      // Replace 'your-api-endpoint' with the actual endpoint to store the data.
      fetch('your-api-endpoint', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ fingerprint: result.visitorId }),
      });
    };

    collectFingerprint();
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default FingerprintCollector;
```

Comment: can you tell me how to just see the preview of the fingerprint without using any api